Selenium returns TimeoutException when I try to enter the email address in a webpage
I am using Selenium and Chrome browser in MacOS to test my code where I am entering some data in a webpages to retrieve data.
Using this code :
driver.get("https://careers-se.icims.com/jobs/70145/login?mobile=false&width=1200&height=500&bga=true&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=330&jun1offset=330")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
enterEmail = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                        "input[name='css_loginName']")))

enterEmail.clear()
enterEmail.send_keys("Hello",Keys.RETURN)


However , when I try to locate the element in a specific webpage , I am receiving a TimeOut Exception error :

File "/Users/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 105, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000102c228cc chromedriver + 4368588
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000102c1ad60 chromedriver + 4336992
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010283ec04 chromedriver + 289796
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000102880e00 chromedriver + 560640
4   chromedriver                        0x00000001028b95ec chromedriver + 792044
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000102875ab4 chromedriver + 514740
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010287650c chromedriver + 517388
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000102be6de8 chromedriver + 4124136
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000102bebbd8 chromedriver + 4144088
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000102bcc7b0 chromedriver + 4016048
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000102bec508 chromedriver + 4146440
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000102bbe264 chromedriver + 3957348
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000102c0be50 chromedriver + 4275792
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000102c0bfcc chromedriver + 4276172
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000102c1a9c0 chromedriver + 4336064
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018922a034 _pthread_start + 136
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000189224e3c thread_start + 8


These are the various methods I've used to mitigate the issues:

Tried to locate the element by various other selection methods like ID , Name or Class. I still received the TimeoutException error.
Tried to find out if the issue was only with that selection, so tried to perform other operations in the webpage -> even this was a failure. I was not able to access any part of the website in Selenium.
Tried using Explicit and Implicit Waits.


did you run without --headless to see browser's window - to see what server sends to browser? You could also check driver.page_source to see if you get expected HTML or some warning with Captcha. And if page uses JavaScript then sometimes it needs time to create all elements and it may need to use Waits (find it in documentation) to wait for elements. And sometimes elements are in <iframe> and it needs to use driver.switch_to.frame()

I checked HTML and it has input inside <iframe> - and browser (and Selenium) treads iframe as separated page - so you have to find this frame and later use it in driver.switch_to.frame(), and later you can search your input

This element is in <iframe> but Selenium treats frame as separate page and it needs to switch to frame to search in this frame.
frame = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe')

driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

enter_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='css_loginName']")))


Full code which I used for tests:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
#import time

# ---

import selenium
print('Selenium:', selenium.__version__)

# ---

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "https://careers-se.icims.com/jobs/70145/login?mobile=false&width=1200&height=500&bga=true&needsRedirect=false&jan1offset=330&jun1offset=330"
driver.get(url)

# - time for Captch -
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
#time.sleep(30)
#input('Press ENTER to continue')

# ---

all_frames = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe')
print('len(all_frames):', len(all_frames)) # check if there are more frames

#frame = all_frames[0]
frame = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe')
print(frame)

driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

# ---

enter_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='css_loginName']")))

enter_email.clear()
enter_email.send_keys("Hello", Keys.RETURN)

input('Press ENTER to close')


Thank You Furas . I modified the code to its iframe and it worked
